# Migration banner text incorrectly describes per-site policy

Tags: bug, migration, migration-notice

When a question is migrated, on the target site it appears with a banner of the form:

> This question was migrated from [source site] because it can be answered on [destination site].

However, just because something **can be** answered on the destination site, doesn't make it off-topic on the source site. This is especially the case on Stack Overflow, which accepts many sorts of questions about installing software used by programmers or using the command line (that could be answered on sites like [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour), etc., depending on the details), a variety of questions about specific game development libraries (that could also be answered on [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tour)), certain questions about algorithms (that could also be answered on [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tour)), etc.

Since we are (to my understanding) only supposed to attempt migration for questions that are *explicitly judged to be off-topic* where they were asked, IMO the banner should explicitly state that the question was off-topic for the source site. That is, after all, **why** the migration was attempted, not simply because the question is *on* topic at the destination.

Comment: I can't see any problem with the current wording. It's a non-issue.

Comment: I thought I explained it clearly. What the message says is not actually true.

Comment: There is an edge case. If a question is on-topic for both the source and destination and the author requests migration, that's another reason for migrating, but the notice would be incorrect in that case.